# Java command line, no response

Tags: java, linux, shell, command-line, output

I am running java application currently.

When I type `java` in the shell, it doesn't produce any output. Also, when I type `java -version`, it doesn't show its version.

I have installed three jdk (jdk1.7.0_79/jdk1.8.0_131/jdk1.8.0_25) on my linux machine (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3). None of them can work now. I can run other commands, such as `ls`, `rm`. It seems not caused by the network.

I can't figure out where or what the problem is. Could you give me a help?

Comment: When you say that it produces no output, you mean not at all? That's surprising... What is the return code? Also, what does the command `which java` return?

Comment: If it doesn't produce a version, I'd expect it to say that it doesn't know what the java command means.  Is the Java /bin folder that contains the Java .exe tools in your PATH?

Comment: @KevinLH I mean it doesn't show any usage information. `which java` returns the jdk directory I use: `~/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java`

Comment: @duffymo Yes, I include the Java /bin folder in the PATH, and I also set the JAVA_HOME

Comment: You did it incorrectly.  If you type "java -version" in a shell you'll get the version.  If you don't, it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Add Java to path. For example, in file that Bash runs whenever it is started

```
~/.bashrc
```

add

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_92
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Naturally the path to JDK after *export JAVA_HOME=* depends on where it's installed.

Comment: Execute 'echo $PATH' in shell and verify that your path really contains the JDK executables 'bin' folder.

Comment: Yes, I 'echo $PATH' in shell, it is there, I really can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I remove a new version glibc in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, now it runs